# Use argument to select which pin to toggle

Tags: python, micropython

I have a board with lets say 20 LEDs that I would like to flash independently for a short duration.
Instead of copying the function 20 times and adjusting the variable name of the pin to flash or using a long if/else ladder, is there a better solution around? Would it be possible to modify the variable name dynamically (probably a bad idea...)?

```
def flash(channel, pulse_length=100):
   pin_1.high()
   time.sleep_us(pulse_length)
   pin_1.low()
```

I would like to use the channel argument to have something like pin_"channel".toggle()

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Use a `list` of pins.

Comment: Any time you have variables with names like `pin_1` and  `pin_2`, it's time consider a list like `pins = []`. Then you can use `pins[1]` and `pins[2]` and problems like this go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* dynamically change the name using something like `globals()[ 'pin_' + str(number)]` but that's pretty ugly and unnecessary.

To expand on the comments, using a dict instead of a list so that individual pins can be named, and incorporating 'toggle' func (note that if the pin is on before 'flash', it will go off then back to on), (uPy on ESP8266 has no Pin.high/low)...

```
pin_dict = {
'red': pin_1,
'blue': pin_2,
'green': pin_3,
}

def toggle(pin):
    pin.value(not pin.value())

def flash(channel, pulse_length=100):
    pin = pin_dict[channel]
    toggle(pin)
    time.sleep_us(pulse_length)
    toggle(pin)

flash('red')
```

if you prefer to use a list, use

```
pin_list = [pin_1, pin_2, pin_3...]
```

and channel is just the index of the pin in the list (flash(0))